# What is the meaning of fully-convolutional cross entropy loss in the function below (image attached)?

Tags: machine-learning, loss-functions, softmax, cross-entropy

I am trying to understand the loss function given below from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.07629).
I do not understand $l_{p}(x_{hw}; y_{hw})$ part.

[image: Loss function]

Answer (score 1):

so am I reading the paper right now. Although I don't get the point of this term "fully convolutional cross-entropy", "fully convolutional" comes from FCN and "cross-entropy" is a very common loss objective.

As per the loss, to my understanding, it is calculated from the layer $\mathcal{X}$, which is eight times smaller than the input image. In this way may he mean that the blue parts of the network is not learned.

[image]

Notice that $\mathcal{X}$ has the dimension of $W_c * H_c * 65$, so $l_p$ is computed upon this 65 channels. $\mathbf{x}_{hwy}$ is the ground truth label where he says in footnote, picked randomly if multiple corner points falls in the same bin.

I think (which I doubt as well) that $\mathbf{x}_{hwk}$ calculates the interest points on the $k$-th channel of the cell $\mathbf{x}_{hw}$. And $\mathbf{x}_{hwy}$ calculates ground-truth label points, it might have multiple points due to mapping.

Hope this could make it a bit clear.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I was a bit confused when they said, "$\mathbf{x}_{hwy}$ is the ground truth label, and picked randomly if multiple corner points fall in the same bin." It means all other entries would be zero and only one point would be selected.

Comment: Therefore, it may have multiple points due to mapping, but then they just choose one point randomly as they randomly pick one corner point. I didn't get that part as well.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to revive a very old discussion but I've just come through this very interesting paper, and I also was not sure on how to interpret the loss function lp(xhw;yhw) :

lp(xhw;yhw) is a cross-entropy loss function which quantifies the difference between a predicted vector Xhw and the Ground truth vector Yhw , both of dimension 65 .i.e. the number of pixels in a 8x8 grid plus the no-interest-point dustbin.

The inderlying assumption in this paper is that there can NOT be more than 1 interest-point in each 8x8 grid. Ykw (Ground Truth) is therefore a 65-size vector with a unique non null element index y and all others 0's . Xhwy is therefore the y-th element (0<y<65) of the predicted vector Xkw of dimension 65 ,

The cross-entropy loss function defined at h,w position between X and Y is composed of a unique non-null element log( predicted probablity of interest-point in bin y) * 1 , all the other 64 elements of Ykw and therefore the cross-entropy are 0

the Loss function Lp(X,Y) is juste the average of all cross-entropy loss functions over all 8x8 grids.

This assumption seems to me an important limit.